Angular Unit testing: How to pass multiple files through include while running ng test from CLI?
I am using ng test to run my unit tests.
I have a scenario where I need to test mutliple spec files which are in different paths.
I am able to do this using angular.json
"test": {
...
"include": ["**/test1.spec.ts","**/test2.spec.ts"],
..
}


I am able to run a single spec file using ng test --include=**/test1.spec.ts
But how to pass an array or multiple spec file path through ng test --include?
FYI: As per angular docs, ng test --include parameter is of type array.
    --include "**/test1.spec.ts,**/test2.spec.ts"
    --include="**/test1.spec.ts","**/test2.spec.ts"
    --include=["**/test1.spec.ts","**/test2.spec.ts"]
    --include=[**/test1.spec.ts,**/test2.spec.ts]


I tried all these possibilities but nothing seemed to help. Can someone help me understand how to pass multiple file path / array to --include through CLI.

I had the same issue.
The Angular docs say the --include parameter is of type array, but the correct syntax isn't clear.
You can specify the --include parameter multiple times, once for each file pattern:
ng test --include **/test1.spec.ts --include **/test2.spec.ts


This worked with slight change ->
ng test -- --include "/test1.spec.ts" --include "/test2.spec.ts"
